# How to set Laravel Routes to redirect to https?

Tags: laravel, ssl, routes, laravel-5

What is the correct way of setting some of my routes on Laravel 5.2 to be redireced using SSL? `http->https`

Also, will I still be able to load `http` assets, or will firefox/chrome/IE have issues if I'm loading `http` components in a secure page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to redirect to `Https` then there is an option in `laravel` `redirect` that you might like to know.

There is laravel helper for redirect called `redirect()`

check the `..vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\helpers.php` file

```
if (! function_exists('redirect')) {
    /**
     * Get an instance of the redirector.
     *
     * @param  string|null  $to
     * @param  int     $status
     * @param  array   $headers
     * @param  bool    $secure
     * @return \Illuminate\Routing\Redirector|\Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse
      */
    function redirect($to = null, $status = 302, $headers = [], $secure = null)
    {
        if (is_null($to)) {
            return app('redirect');
        }

    return app('redirect')->to($to, $status, $headers, $secure);
    }
}
```

check the parameters `$to = null, $status = 302, $headers = [], $secure = null`

There is an option for `Https` as `$secure`, set it to true and there you will get an `Https` redirect for EX:
   `redirect('/', 302, [], true)`

**NOTE:** *I also worked with this kind of thing and I did get an `404 error` when the site is running on `Https` and assets loading trough `Http` as I remember, better to check it again. :)*

there is a helper for loading secure assets [`secure_asset()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/helpers#method-secure-asset)

---

I have faced some difficulties when testing in `Http` and production in `Https`, some assets are not loading and re-directions not working, What we did is create a separate helper to drop the schema ,

```
if (! function_exists('urlWithoutSchema')) {
    /**
     * Generate a url for the application without schema.
     *
     * @param  string  $path
         * @param  mixed   $parameters
     * @param  bool    $secure
     * @return string
     */
    function urlWithoutSchema($path = null, $parameters = array(), $secure = null)
    {
        $url = app('url')->to($path, $parameters, $secure);

        return str_replace(parse_url($url, PHP_URL_SCHEME).':', '', $url);
    }
}
```

THEN `urlWithoutSchema("https://laravel.com/")` will results in `//laravel.com/`

IF you use `redirect(urlWithoutSchema("your-site-name.com"))` then it will redirect to `//your-site-name.com/` that means if you using `Https` site will redirect with `Https` otherwise to `Http`.

Same thing can be use for loading assets like,

```
<link href="{{ urlWithoutSchema('css/vendor.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Then when you running on `Http` `css/vendor.css` will load through `Http`, and if you running on `Https` assets will load via `Https`.

Using this you can avoid some issues regurding environments which has `Https` and which hasn't `Https`